# Is there a simpler or better way of saying "promises that hold no meaning"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, vocabulary

Is there a simpler or better way of saying "promises that hold no meaning" or "promises without meaning"?

Comment: _You'd better hold on to your promises because you bet you'll get what you deserve_ (cit.)

Answer (score 42):

[Empty promises.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/empty_promise)

> empty promise
>
> (idiomatic) A promise that is either not going to be carried out, worthless or meaningless.

Comment: Yep, this is definitely the most idiomatic term.  After that I'd go with (duh!) "meaningless promises".

Comment: Also (a distant second) "hollow promise".

Answer (score 4):

In my Google searches, in several books "vacuous promise" appears as a synonym for "empty promise". It has a more dramatic tone that may or may not be a good fit with your work. It can convey undertones of thoughtlessness on the part of the person making the promise.

From Google's definition:

> adjective: vacuous
>
> 1. having or showing a lack of thought or intelligence; mindless.
>    "a vacuous smile"
>    synonyms:   blank, vacant, expressionless, deadpan, inscrutable, inexpressive, poker-faced, emotionless, impassive, absent, absent-minded, uninterested, empty, glassy, stony, wooden, motionless, lifeless, inanimate More
>    antonyms:   expressive, meaningful, thinking, intelligent
> 2. (archaic) empty.

Answer (score 2):

An ***empty promise*** or a ***false/fake promise*** can be used. But an empty promise is the best one.

Answer (score 1):

More specialized or poetic phrases:

- "promises in the dark"
- "campaign promises"
- [you made me] "promises, promises"
- "lies"

Answer (score 0):

Or even you want example from Song of Fire and Ice: *words are wind*

Answer (score -3):

i would say "truism" for a promise which is true, but meaningless. e.g. suppose i say "i promise to give to charity at least as much this year as last year". that would be a meaningless (but true) promise, if i gave nothing to charity last year.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truism

i would say "empty promise" for a promise which the speaker has no intention of trying to keep and/or no expectation of being held accountable. e.g. "i promise to come back before i die". that promise is meaningful, but not necessarily true.

Comment: A truism is a commonly repeated statement that is true. It has nothing to do with promises that may or may not be true.

Comment: i was using "truism" in it's logical sense.  "a proposition that states nothing beyond what is implied by any of its terms." you could use tautology if you prefer. i have updated the answer to be more clear. source: https://www.google.com/search?q=truism